# Несоответствие ожидаемому результату работы IntStream

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных, java-stream, synchronized

Разбираюсь в многопоточности, дошёл до класса Phaser. Встретил пример.

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser();
    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> {
      phaser.register();
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + phaser);
        }).start();
    });
```

Вывод работы этого кода:

```
Thread-1 java.util.concurrent.Phaser@42b4d62c[phase = 0 parties = 3 arrived = 0]
Thread-0 java.util.concurrent.Phaser@42b4d62c[phase = 0 parties = 3 arrived = 0]
Thread-2 java.util.concurrent.Phaser@42b4d62c[phase = 0 parties = 3 arrived = 0]
```

Сразу **parties = 3** да и ещё в **первой** строке вывода. Думал будет reg() sout ,reg() sout, reg() sout() и **parties = 1**, **parties = 2**, **parties = 3**.

Искал в интернете(в т.ч. и в англоязычном) - ближе всего объяснение такого поведения в "планировщике", а там зарылся и тупик.

Может в не в ту степь пошёл: пробовал менять местами строки в этом куске кода, чтобы увидеть логику - безрезультатно.

Объясните, откуда программа знала, что  **parties = 3** до выполнения всего цикла (0,3)?

Comment: Если бы добавили существенную задержку между запусками отдельных потоков, то могли бы увидеть меняющиеся значения `parties = 1, 2, 3`

Comment: @NowhereMan спасибо за комментарий, да, послушал вас - обложил register() слипами и получилось как и хотелось.

Answer (score 1):

Никакой магии нет. Привыкайте к асинхронности. Есть цикл, который выполняется в главном потоке и делает 2 операции - регистрирует участника и запускает новый поток. Запуск потока (вернее запуск и выполнение его Runnable) операция недешёвая и небыстрая. Тем более основной поток не дожидается самого факта запуска, скидывая эту проблему на JVM, и спокойненько идёт дальше выполнять цикл где снова меняет состояния фазера. К моменту, когда все 3 потока доходят до вывода на консоль, фазер уже зарегистрировал всех участников (ну или почти всех). Чтобы увидеть хронологию происходящего, достаточно расставить временные логи происходящего.

```
        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> {
            phaser.register();
            System.out.println("Register: " + System.nanoTime());
            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("Output:   " + System.nanoTime());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + phaser);
            }).start();
        });
```

ну и собственно логи

```
Register: 2452906851214400
Register: 2452906856518900
Register: 2452906856672000
Output:   2452906856816400
Output:   2452906856921500
Output:   2452906856968400
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробные пояснения, есть вопрос, как вы писали: "...и спокойненько идёт дальше выполнять цикл где снова меняет состояния фазера..." т.е., по другому говоря, главный поток идёт дальше регистрировать участников и, после того как всех register(), переходить на след. фазу? Я правильно все понял?

Comment: В вашем примере нет механизма ожидания и перехода на следующую фазу. Для этого используется метод фазера `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()`.

Comment: Невнимательно написал последний комментарий. А в этом случае?
Update: 
`new Thread(() -> {System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + phaser);            phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
System.out.println("after " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + phaser);)).start();
`

Comment: Да. Пока все зарегистрированные потоки не дойдут до точки ожидания смены фазы, фаза не поменяется.